# Setter in Javascript + BackBone is this the right way?

Tags: javascript, syntax, backbone.js

I got this "object"

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Fetus',
        age: 0,
        children: []
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind("change:name", function() {
            var name = this.get("name");
            alert("Changed my name to " + name);
        });
    },
    adopt: function(newChildsName) {
        this.get("children").push(newChildsName);
    },
    setName: function(name) {
        this.set({
            name: name
        });
    }
});
```

Can't the set method `setName` be done like this :
I tried but they don't work

```
setName: function(name){
  this.get(name) = name;
}
```

or

```
setName: function(name){
  this[name].set(name);
}
```

Is there another way ? I can't go around thinking the original way is too ugly to use.

Comment: That's the standard way as far as I know, I'll let a more experienced Backbone user answer if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity I am changing the argument name to `newName`. While:

```
this.set({name: newName});
```

means: set a value of an attribute named `name` with new value of `newName` parameter (correct), this form:

```
setName: function(newName){
  this.get(newName) = newName;
}
```

does nothing. It gets an attribute whose name is provided in `newName` parameter and returns it. The assignment has no effect.

On the other hand this:

```
setName: function(newName){
  this[newName].set(newName);
}
```

will probably throw an error. `this` is a Backbone model object. It contains `attributes` property, so probably:

```
this.attributes[newName] = newName;
```

is more reasonable (change the attribute whose name is passed in `newName` parameter to `newName` value. However in this case the `change` event won't be triggered. But let me guess, this is what you really wanted:

```
setAttr: function(name, value){
  var diff = {};
  diff[name] = value;
  this.set(diff);
}
```

In this case you can call:

```
model.setAttr('id', 7);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
model.setAttr({id: 7});
```

and triggers `change:id` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The original way looks best to me. You MUST call set() on the model for Backbone's event system to work properly. Your two examples don't make much sense (i.e. assigning a value to a value, and calling set() on a value instead of on the model.)

I actually think adding your own setName method is kind of odd. Anyone programming Backbone.js should know to use the built-in set() function on model instances to set property values.